# Footer not at bottom of the page when page gets longer

Tags: html, css, footer

I am making a memory game for desktop and mobile with a reset button as a footer. The footer looks fine in desktop view. But when viewing on smaller screen widths the content starts overflowing the footer because the page grows longer. I want the footer to stay at the bottom of the page below the content at all times. I've tried multiple solution from here but none of them have worked so far in my situation.

CSS:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: url(http://cur.cursors-4u.net/games/gam-14/gam1340.cur), auto;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: leaguefont;
  src: url("../fonts/font.ttf");
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-image: url("../images/other/background.png");
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
/*--------------------------------------------navbar*/
.nav-link {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem 5rem;
}

a {
  font-family: leaguefont;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ff9900, #ffff66);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  font-size: 4rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

/*--------------------------------------------memory card containers*/

.memory-game1,
.memory-game2,
.memory-game3 {
  min-height: 40rem;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  perspective: 62.5rem;
  max-width: 100vw;
  justify-content: center;
}
.memory-game1 {
  width: 40rem;
}
.memory-game2 {
  width: 60rem;
}
.memory-game3 {
  width: 80rem;
}

/*--------------------------------------------memory cards*/

.memory-card,
.memory-card2,
.memory-card3 {
  height: calc(33.333% - 0.625rem);
  margin: 0.313rem;
  position: relative;
  transform: scale(1);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  min-width: 149px;
}
.memory-card {
  width: calc(25% - 0.625rem);
}
.memory-card2 {
  width: calc(16.666% - 0.625rem);
}
.memory-card3 {
  width: calc(12.5% - 0.625rem);
}

.front-face,
.back-face {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1.25rem;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0.513rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#1c7ccc, #00ccff);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

/*--------------------------------------------click animation*/

div.memory-card:active,
div.memory-card2:active,
div.memory-card3:active {
  transform: scale(0.97);
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}

.memory-card.flip,
.memory-card2.flip,
.memory-card3.flip {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.front-face {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
/*--------------------------------------------Footer*/
footer {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3.75rem 0rem;
  font-family: leaguefont;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ff9900, #ffff66);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-align: center;
}
/*--------------------------------------------Media queries*/
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  a {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
  }
}

HTML:
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <title>League of Memory</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
      <link
         rel="stylesheet"
         href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
         integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
         crossorigin="anonymous"
         />
      <script defer src="assets/js/cards.js"></script>
   </head>
   <!-------------------------------------------------navbar-->
   <nav>
      <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="index.html">level one</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="leveltwo.html">level two</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="levelthree.html">level three</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </nav>
   <body>
      <!-----------------------------------------------memory cards (12)-->
      <section class="memory-game1">
         <div class="memory-card" data-frontface="Caitlyn">
            <img
               class="front-face"
               src="assets/images/champions/caitlyn.png"
               alt="Caitlyn"
               />
            <img
               class="back-face"
               src="assets/images/other/cardlogo.png"
               alt="League Logo"
               />
         </div>
         <div class="memory-card" data-frontface="Caitlyn">
            <img
               class="front-face"
               src="assets/images/champions/caitlyn.png"
               alt="Caitlyn"
               />
            <img
               class="back-face"
               src="assets/images/other/cardlogo.png"
               alt="League Logo"
               />
         </div>
         <div class="memory-card" data-frontface="Darius">
            <img
               class="front-face"
               src="assets/images/champions/darius.png"
               alt="Darius"
               />
            <img
               class="back-face"
               src="assets/images/other/cardlogo.png"
               alt="League Logo"
               />
         </div>
         <div class="memory-card" data-frontface="Darius">
            <img
               class="front-face"
               src="assets/images/champions/darius.png"
               alt="Darius"
               />
            <img
               class="back-face"
               src="assets/images/other/cardlogo.png"
               alt="League Logo"
               />
         </div>
         <div class="memory-card" data-frontface="Ezreal">
            <img
               class="front-face"
               src="assets/images/champions/ezreal.png"
               alt="Ezreal"
               />
            <img
               class="back-face"
               src="assets/images/other/cardlogo.png"
               alt="League Logo"
               />
         </div>
         <div class="memory-card" data-frontface="Ezreal">
            <img
               class="front-face"
               src="assets/images/champions/ezreal.png"
               alt="Ezreal"
               />
            <img
               class="back-face"
               src="assets/images/other/cardlogo.png"
               alt="League Logo"
               />
         </div>
         <div class="memory-card" data-frontface="Gangplank">
            <img
               class="front-face"
               src="assets/images/champions/gangplank.png"
               alt="Gangplank"
               />
            <img
               class="back-face"
               src="assets/images/other/cardlogo.png"
               alt="League Logo"
               />
         </div>
         <div class="memory-card" data-frontface="Gangplank">
            <img
               class="front-face"
               src="assets/images/champions/gangplank.png"
               alt="Gangplank"
               />
            <img
               class="back-face"
               src="assets/images/other/cardlogo.png"
               alt="League Logo"
               />
         </div>
         <div class="memory-card" data-frontface="Graves">
            <img
               class="front-face"
               src="assets/images/champions/graves.png"
               alt="Graves"
               />
            <img
               class="back-face"
               src="assets/images/other/cardlogo.png"
               alt="League Logo"
               />
         </div>
         <div class="memory-card" data-frontface="Graves">
            <img
               class="front-face"
               src="assets/images/champions/graves.png"
               alt="Graves"
               />
            <img
               class="back-face"
               src="assets/images/other/cardlogo.png"
               alt="League Logo"
               />
         </div>
         <div class="memory-card" data-frontface="Katarina">
            <img
               class="front-face"
               src="assets/images/champions/katarina.png"
               alt="Katarina"
               />
            <img
               class="back-face"
               src="assets/images/other/cardlogo.png"
               alt="League Logo"
               />
         </div>
         <div class="memory-card" data-frontface="Katarina">
            <img
               class="front-face"
               src="assets/images/champions/katarina.png"
               alt="Katarina"
               />
            <img
               class="back-face"
               src="assets/images/other/cardlogo.png"
               alt="League Logo"
               />
         </div>
      </section>
      <footer>
         <div>
            <a href="index.html">
            RESET
            </a>
         </div>
      </footer>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I put the nav section between the body tags. HTML-height:100% removed as css. Unnecessary.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: url(http://cur.cursors-4u.net/games/gam-14/gam1340.cur), auto;
}
 /*html {
  height: 100%;
}*/

@font-face {
  font-family: leaguefont;
  src: url("../fonts/font.ttf");
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-image: url("../images/other/background.png");
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
/*--------------------------------------------navbar*/
.nav-link {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem 5rem;
}

a {
  font-family: leaguefont;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ff9900, #ffff66);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  font-size: 4rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

/*--------------------------------------------memory card containers*/

.memory-game1,
.memory-game2,
.memory-game3 {
  min-height: 40rem;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  perspective: 62.5rem;
  max-width: 100vw;
  justify-content: center;
}
.memory-game1 {
  width: 40rem;
}
.memory-game2 {
  width: 60rem;
}
.memory-game3 {
  width: 80rem;
}

/*--------------------------------------------memory cards*/

.memory-card,
.memory-card2,
.memory-card3 {
  height: calc(33.333% - 0.625rem);
  margin: 0.313rem;
  position: relative;
  transform: scale(1);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  min-width: 149px;
}
.memory-card {
  width: calc(25% - 0.625rem);
}
.memory-card2 {
  width: calc(16.666% - 0.625rem);
}
.memory-card3 {
  width: calc(12.5% - 0.625rem);
}

.front-face,
.back-face {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1.25rem;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0.513rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#1c7ccc, #00ccff);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

/*--------------------------------------------click animation*/

div.memory-card:active,
div.memory-card2:active,
div.memory-card3:active {
  transform: scale(0.97);
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}

.memory-card.flip,
.memory-card2.flip,
.memory-card3.flip {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.front-face {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
/*--------------------------------------------Footer*/
footer {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3.75rem 0rem;
  font-family: leaguefont;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ff9900, #ffff66);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-align: center;
}
/*--------------------------------------------Media queries*/
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  a {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Document</title>


   
</head>



<body>
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
           <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="index.html">level one</a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="leveltwo.html">level two</a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="levelthree.html">level three</a>
           </li>
        </ul>
     </nav>
  
    <!-----------------------------------------------memory cards (12)-->
    <section class="memory-game1">
        <div class="memory-card" data-frontface="Caitlyn">
           <img
              class="front-face"
              src="assets/images/champions/caitlyn.png"
              alt="Caitlyn"
              />
           <img
              class="back-face"
              src="assets/images/other/cardlogo.png"
              alt="League Logo"
              />
        </div>
        <div class="memory-card" data-frontface="Caitlyn">
           <img
              class="front-face"
              src="assets/images/champions/caitlyn.png"
              alt="Caitlyn"
              />
           <img
              class="back-face"
              src="assets/images/other/cardlogo.png"
              alt="League Logo"
              />
        </div>
        <div class="memory-card" data-frontface="Darius">
           <img
              class="front-face"
              src="assets/images/champions/darius.png"
              alt="Darius"
              />
           <img
              class="back-face"
              src="assets/images/other/cardlogo.png"
              alt="League Logo"
              />
        </div>
        <div class="memory-card" data-frontface="Darius">
           <img
              class="front-face"
              src="assets/images/champions/darius.png"
              alt="Darius"
              />
           <img
              class="back-face"
              src="assets/images/other/cardlogo.png"
              alt="League Logo"
              />
        </div>
        <div class="memory-card" data-frontface="Ezreal">
           <img
              class="front-face"
              src="assets/images/champions/ezreal.png"
              alt="Ezreal"
              />
           <img
              class="back-face"
              src="assets/images/other/cardlogo.png"
              alt="League Logo"
              />
        </div>
        <div class="memory-card" data-frontface="Ezreal">
           <img
              class="front-face"
              src="assets/images/champions/ezreal.png"
              alt="Ezreal"
              />
           <img
              class="back-face"
              src="assets/images/other/cardlogo.png"
              alt="League Logo"
              />
        </div>
        <div class="memory-card" data-frontface="Gangplank">
           <img
              class="front-face"
              src="assets/images/champions/gangplank.png"
              alt="Gangplank"
              />
           <img
              class="back-face"
              src="assets/images/other/cardlogo.png"
              alt="League Logo"
              />
        </div>
        <div class="memory-card" data-frontface="Gangplank">
           <img
              class="front-face"
              src="assets/images/champions/gangplank.png"
              alt="Gangplank"
              />
           <img
              class="back-face"
              src="assets/images/other/cardlogo.png"
              alt="League Logo"
              />
        </div>
        <div class="memory-card" data-frontface="Graves">
           <img
              class="front-face"
              src="assets/images/champions/graves.png"
              alt="Graves"
              />
           <img
              class="back-face"
              src="assets/images/other/cardlogo.png"
              alt="League Logo"
              />
        </div>
        <div class="memory-card" data-frontface="Graves">
           <img
              class="front-face"
              src="assets/images/champions/graves.png"
              alt="Graves"
              />
           <img
              class="back-face"
              src="assets/images/other/cardlogo.png"
              alt="League Logo"
              />
        </div>
        <div class="memory-card" data-frontface="Katarina">
           <img
              class="front-face"
              src="assets/images/champions/katarina.png"
              alt="Katarina"
              />
           <img
              class="back-face"
              src="assets/images/other/cardlogo.png"
              alt="League Logo"
              />
        </div>
        <div class="memory-card" data-frontface="Katarina">
           <img
              class="front-face"
              src="assets/images/champions/katarina.png"
              alt="Katarina"
              />
           <img
              class="back-face"
              src="assets/images/other/cardlogo.png"
              alt="League Logo"
              />
        </div>
     </section>
     <footer>
        <div>
           <a href="index.html">
           RESET
           </a>
        </div>
     </footer>




        <script>
          
            




        </script>



        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: HTML-height:100% was indeed unnecessary, and it's probably better to but the nav in the body element. But this doesn't actually solve my problem with the footer.

Comment: and I may have misinterpreted it because your photos didn't show, and I didn't see the real problem. Can you point out the problem through an example where the photos are exactly as obvious ?

Comment: The snippet does indeed not show to problem that well. Here I have a link to the live version of my site: https://kris965.github.io/league-of-memory/ at the bottom of the page there is footer( the reset button) which is just a link refreshing the page. Try resizing the browser window until you have to scroll down to see the content. The footer stays at the same place instead of moving down with the content itself. I want it to stay under the content at all times.

Comment: Now it happened. I'm downloading the repo from your Github. I'll look.

Comment: I got the footer at the bottom now by wrapping the whole page in the container added position: relative; and
  min-height: 100vh; to it and added position: absolute; and
  bottom: 0; to the footer. But now the height of the memory cards are messed up. https://gyazo.com/3fcd29f19ec6d5d656af93295f79ed7f

Comment: I downloaded the GitHub Repon, but I couldn't open it properly. If you can tell me how to open it properly , I'd like to take a look. As far as I can see in general, html and css formatting is incorrect and irregular. Therefore, when you change the properties of any item, the other items are disordered.